# What is best way to assign the type of an array that has properties using typescript?

Tags: typescript

Here is my type of interest - an array with properties.

```
type MyArray = string[];

interface MyArrayWithProperties extends MyArray {
    someProperty: boolean
  }
```

This is the only way I've been able to assign the type.

```
let arr : any = ['a','b', 'c']; //must declare array as any

arr.someProperty = true //then add the property

const arrWProps = arr as MyArrayWithProperties; //then cast as type
```

Is a better way? Usually I don't need to build variables in steps as `any` before setting the real type.

Comment: `type MyArrayWithProperties = string[] & { someProperty: boolean };` most likely does the same thing as what you want, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Object.assign` can be used to create an array literal and assign a value to it all at once before finally putting it into the variable on the left (with the right type).

```
const arr: MyArrayWithProperties = Object.assign(['a','b', 'c'], { someProperty: true });
```

That said, I'd usually recommend not putting arbitrary key-value pairs onto arrays like this - programmers will generally expect an array to contain *only* properties that arrays usually have (numeric indicies, `.length`, and array methods). There aren't any rules against it, but you might consider if there are other ways you might structure the code to get the same effect.

Comment: yeah, after using the array w/properties for just 1 hour I regret doing it.